# What would the shape of the trajectories of two revolving bodies whose centers of revolution are each other look like?

Tags: geometry

If earth was represented by a point X and the sun was represented by a point Y. Ignoring physical forces such as gravity, if the earth were to rotate around the sun, and the sun were to rotate around the earth, what would the trajectory of both look like? Let's also assume that the force and speed of rotation are the same for both. Would the trajectory ever collide? Also, what would the trajectory of both point X and Y look like. I doubt the respective trajectories of point X and Y would look like a circle. However, I can't picture what the trajectories would look like.

Answer (score 0):

You can imagine a rigid stick connecting the earth and sun.  If the stick rotates around its midpoint, both the earth and sun describe a circle with radius half the length of the stick.  From the point of view of each the earth sun, the other is revolving around it.  In inertial space, each makes a circle with radius half the distance between the earth and sun.

The center of rotation can be anywhere along the stick.  If it is closer to the sun, the sun will describe a small circle in inertial space and the earth will describe a large one.  Again each will see the other revolving around it with a period of one year at the same distance.  This is how the system works (ignoring the eccentricity of the earth's orbit) in real life with the center of rotation being the center of mass of the two bodies, much closer to the center of the sun than the earth.

Added:  here is a picture.  The left is the first paragraph.  The earth and sun are B and C, revolving at the same speed around A.  As they go around, each sees the other circling it.  The right is the second paragraph.  The earth is E, revolving on the big circle.  The sun is F, revolving on the small circle at the same angular speed around D.  Again each sees the other circling it once per year.  As the sun is much more massive than the earth, in real life D is very close to F.

[image]

Comment: Is there a picture of what you are describing? I am having trouble visualizing it.

Comment: But from what I understood, you're describing the shape of the trajectories if the center of rotation for both is static. What I was asking for is what the shape of the trajectories would be if the center of the rotation of the sun would be the earth, and the center of rotation of the earth would be the earth.

Comment: We can define a frame where the center is static. As I said, each body sees the other revolving around it. In the earth frame the sun’s path is just a circle. What frame were you asking for the path in?

Comment: If the center of rotation is each other, then why are you saying that the center of rotation can be anywhere on the stick instead of saying that the center of rotation is dynamic and should be F for E and E for F?

Comment: We have three frames of reference here.  One is centered on the earth observing the sun.  One is centered on the sun observing the earth.  One is relative to far away.  The center of rotation of the stick is measured in the far away frame.  We can ask what part of the system does not move in the far away frame, which gives us the external center of rotation.

Comment: Regardless of the frame of reference, it doesn't make sense to say that the shape of rotation is circular since the center of rotation is moving. I don't think you understood the question.

Comment: When you say the sun goes around the earth in a circular motion, you specify the stick I proposed.  That gets you the earth going around the sun as well.  You can now take any one point of the system and move as you wish.  You can fix the earth, the sun, or any point on the stick, all of which make the earth and sun move in circles in inertial space.  You can also move the earth any way you want, then make the sun be in the right place so it is seen to be orbiting the earth.  You have not supplied enough definition to say what the path is like in inertial space.

Comment: By the way, I am not familiar with a lot of the concepts you used, so I can't determine how sound your arguments and explanations are, but would you agree with Yves that the trajectories would be hypo/epi-cycloids depending on how you see it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say a lot about the kind of "rotation" you are thinking of.

So let us assume that the distance between the two bodies is constant and that line segment rotates in a plane at constant angular speed in some absolute frame.

Then seen from the Earth, the Sun describes a circle at constant angular speed, and conversely. Provided the Earth doesn't rotate on itself around an axis: then the Sun would describe a complex, in general non periodical curve, inscribed on a sphere. As far as I know, this curve has no name.

Now if you look at those bodies "from outside", for instance in a spaceship travelling in a straight line at constant speed, both the Earth and Sun describe a kind of helix, inscribed on the surface of an elliptical cylindre.

In a limit case (motion of the spaceship in the rotation plane), the trajectories will be hypo/epi-cycloids.

Comment: Is there a picture of what you are describing? I am having trouble visualizing it.

Comment: @tefisjb: no, I don't.